# Android custom ArrayAdapter : "unfortunately, app has stopped" while scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, android-adapter

i don't understand why this code results in "unfortunately, android3 has stopped"

i have tried so many solutions i found online , but none seems to be working , i don't know the cause , please someone should help me out.

Here is my activity_main.xml file

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/theListView">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is my MainActivity.java file

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package  com.snoott.android3;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public  class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String names[] = {"Dustin Moskovitz" , "Elon Musk" , "Bill Gates" , "Mark Zuckerberg" , "Larry Page" ,
                "Sergey Brin" , "Steve Jobs" , "Tim Cook"};
        final Integer[] images = {R.drawable.dustin , R.drawable.elon , R.drawable.gate , R.drawable.mark , R.drawable.page ,
                R.drawable.sergey , R.drawable.steve , R.drawable.tim};



        final String descriptions [] = {"Co-founder of Facebook" , "CEO Tesla" , "Founder Microsoft" , "Co-founder , CEO of Facebook" ,
                "Chairman Alphabet Inc." , "President Alphabet Inc." , "Founder Apple" , "CEO Apple"};

        ArrayList<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<Profile>();

        for(int i = 0; i < descriptions.length; ++i){
            profiles.add(new Profile(names[i] , images[i] , descriptions[i]));

        }






        ArrayAdapter<Profile> listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this , profiles);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.theListView);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);



    }

}
```

here is my Profile.java file

**Profile.java :**

```
package com.snoott.android3;

public class Profile {

    public String name;
    public Integer profileImage;
    public String description;


    public  Profile(){}

    public Profile(String name , Integer profile , String description){
        this.name = name;
        this.profileImage = profile;
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

here is my CustomAdapter file:

**CustomAdapter.java:**

```
package com.snoott.android3;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Profile>{


    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Profile> resource) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_listview , resource);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        Profile currentProfile = (Profile)getItem(position);

        if(convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_listview , parent , false);
            viewHolder.nameTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profileName);
            viewHolder.profileImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            viewHolder.descriptionTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profileDescription);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }

        viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(currentProfile.name);
        viewHolder.profileImage.setImageResource(currentProfile.profileImage);
        viewHolder.descriptionTextView.setText(currentProfile.description);

        return  convertView;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView nameTextView;
        TextView descriptionTextView;
        ImageView profileImage;

    }
}
```

**custom_listview.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mark"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mark Zuckerberg"
            android:textFontWeight="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/profileName"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="CEO of Facebook"
            android:id="@+id/profileDescription"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**build.gradle** :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.snoott.android3"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: If your app stops running then there is a corresponding Logcat entry - please add it to your question

Comment: If your app stops running after you have scrolled down a little bit, it may be because the images are just too big and since all of them are loading at the same time the system runs out of memory and forces it to stop

Comment: Try removing the image from your listview and check if it still crashes, if it still does its almost sure that the images being loaded is whats crashing it.
you need to lower the resolution and manage them correctly

Comment: Post the error in the logs.

Comment: share **custom_listview.xml** layout

Comment: @KrishnaSharma just did

Comment: Share the crash log please

Comment: @KosiEric I have just ran your code on my machine, everything works fine. Just make sure you have added dependency **implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'** In build.gradle

Comment: This is my build.gradle

Comment: Looks perfect, can you please share the crash log ? Just copy from studio logcat

Comment: it's too long..how do i go about it

Comment: Just search starting with Exception ? you will get relevant logs

Answer (score 1):

It must be throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because arrays `names` and `images` **length is 8** but `description` array **length is 9**. Just keep all the arrays item size equal.

Comment: Just counted it, they are the same length

Comment: @KosiEric Just make sure you have added this dependency **implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'** in app gradle